# tsql - updating a table from a select statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two tables. TableA and TableB.
TableA holds a varbinary(max) column - named [BinaryA]
TableB holds a column (named "Volume", type "Long") that contains each varbinary volume.

in order to select all volumes I query

```
SELECT ID, MyVolume = DATALENGTH([Binary])
FROM [VAULT].[TABLEA]
```

than, I want to update tableB with its volume.

I then write

```
update [TableB] 
set [VOLUME]  = ( SELECT MyVolume = DATALENGTH([Binary])
              FROM [VAULT].[TABLEA] ab
          WHERE id = ab.[Id])
```

I receive than

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Volume', table 'MySchema.Asset';
column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
```

Though I dont receive any NULL when I run

```
SELECT ID, MyVolume = DATALENGTH([Binary])
FROM [VAULT].[TABLEA]
```

Comment: Are TableA and TableB related?  Setting your VOLUME to your subselect will fail if your subselect returns more than one row.  Are you trying to join tableA to tableB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this query:

```
UPDATE TableB 
SET TableB.[VOLUME] = DATALENGTH([T2.Binary])
FROM TableB
INNER JOIN [VAULT].[TABLEA] T2 ON TableB.TAL_ID = T2.TAL_ID
```

Assuming that TableB and [VAULT].[TABLEA] are related by ID field.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE tableB
SET    [volume] = (SELECT RetrieveAccountNumber.AccountNumber 
                          FROM   RetrieveAccountNumber 
                          WHERE  tableB.leadid =RetrieveAccountNumber.LeadID) 
WHERE Sales_Import.leadid = (SELECT  RetrieveAccountNumber.LeadID 
                             FROM   RetrieveAccountNumber 
                             WHERE  tableB.leadid = RetrieveAccountNumber.LeadID)
```

Comment: How is RetrieveAccountNumber related to TableA?  Where did RetrieveAccountNumber come from?  It's not in the OP question.