# Sql update trouble

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Please see the screenshot below.  I am trying to update `tid` with `sid` where teacher's emailaddress equals student's email address.  I've tried different methods and it's either I get an empty result or multipart identifier error.  Kindly help.

[image: screenshot of the problem]

For instance, the kind of answer I expect would be, **tid** on row 1 would be 3, row 2 would be 2, row3 would be 2, and row 4, 1

Comment: Please post the query you attempted. This should be very straightforward `WHERE studentemail = teacheremail`

Comment: Can you show what you have tried, so that we can guide you appropriately with your homework?

Comment: @Kris, your query returns an empty row.

Comment: Here another [tsql - updating a table from a select statement](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17047692/1563878)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should just be something simple like

```
Update s
Set tid = t.sid
From table s
Inner join table t on s.teacheremail = t.studentemail
```

Comment: You did it!  Thanks a lot!