# Update column value from a column in a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables
1) Weekly hits
2) Monthly hits

Every week for a month a column in the monthly hit will increment itself using data form the weekly hit table.

The weekly hits table has information that looks like this:

```
Name   Date      TypeofHit     Location

Jeff  10-10-12      Bunt       New York
Sally 10-12-12      Bunt       Wyoming
 Joe  10-12-12      Hit        Texas
Mark  10-14-12      Hit        Ohio
James 10-15-12      Miss       California
```

The Monthly table is structured like this.

```
TypeofHit   TCount
   Bunt       2
   Hit        2
   Miss       1
```

What I want to to do is add total TypesofHits from the Weekly table into the Monthly Table

```
SELECT COUNT(*) From WEEKLY GROUP BY TypeofHit
```

The above gives me the numbers I need to add to the Monthly table, but I am having trouble with the proper formatting with the Update statement. I have tried

```
UPDATE Monthly SET TCount + (SELECT Count(*) from Weekly GROUP BY TypeofHit) WHERE Monthly.TypeofHit = Weekly.TypeofHit
```

I am using MSSMS

Comment: Maybe this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17047692/1563878) will be useful

Answer (score 0):

You need to `JOIN` both tables:

```
UPDATE M
SET M.TCount = M.TCount + W.TCount
FROM Monthly M
INNER JOIN (SELECT  TypeofHit,
                    COUNT(*) TCount
            FROM Weekly
            GROUP BY TypeofHit) W
    ON M.TypeofHit = W.TypeofHit
```

And, by the way, I'm missing the date on the monthly table, you need to make sure to join them by that column too for this to make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a update statement for updating the monthly table, then you can use the below

```
UPDATE M
SET M.TCount = M.TCount + A.TypeCount
FROM Monthly M 
JOIN (
select count(1) TypeCount, TypeofHit   from Weekly GROUP BY TypeofHit
) A
on A.TypeofHit = M.TypeofHit
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this query (here an **[EXAMPLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8cf67/3))**, this works perfectly:

```
WITH tempTable1 AS
(
    SELECT TypeofHit, COUNT(*) as c FROM Weekly
    GROUP BY TypeofHit
)
UPDATE Monthly  
SET Monthly.TCount = Monthly.TCount + T2.c
FROM Monthly
INNER JOIN tempTable1 T2 ON Monthly.TypeofHit = T2.TypeofHit
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE a
   SET a.TCount = a.TCount + b.TCount
  FROM Monthly a,(  select TypeofHit, count(*) TCount   
                      from WEEKLY 
                  GROUP BY TypeofHit
                 ) b
 WHERE a.TypeofHit = b.TypeofHit
```